# Closing multiple projects in Visual Studio

Tags: c#

I have two projects running in Visual Studio but whenever I exit one the other keeps running. How can I close both?

Ps: I'm using Application.Exit() to close the first one

Comment: what kind of projects?  how do you start them? are they referenced or independent ?

Comment: The main one is a windows forms and the second is a ASP.NET Core Web API. They are in the same solution and both have Program.cs. I setted the solution to initialize multiple projects. The win forms has a dependency from the API

Comment: If you set up both projects as startup projects, you simply click the "Stop Debugging" button. Your code has nothing to do with that.

Comment: Hitting the stop button doesn't stop them both? Are you launching one or more project "Without Debugging"?

Comment: Actually, I have a button "Close the application" in the Win Forms and, on the event click of this button, the application is supposed to close as a whole. That's why I said I'm using Application.Exit(), sorry for not being all that clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use `Application.Exit()` to close the first process, and you want to close the second process at the same time, try adding the following lines immediately before you call `Application.Exit()`:

```
Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("SecondProcess");
processes[0].Kill();
```

where `SecondProcess` is the process name of your second process. (You will also need to add a `using` reference to `System.Diagnostics`.)

This code assumes exactly one such process will be running; if that's not necessarily the case, you might need to do more.

**Use with caution:** killing a running process like this might not be advisable! Other methods are possible and probably better but without more information about your exact setup it's hard to know which approach to suggest.

Comment: There are different ways to stop a program. The "nice" way is to send an interrupt signal, and the not-so-nice way is to kill the process. (OP) you might want to look into the nicer method.